# Using Lucene Highlighter infrastructure to mark up arbitrary text

Tags: lucene, highlight

I am using Lucene 3.5 in a client-server architecture as follows: the client issues a query to the server. The server returns a list of terms used in the query, and a list of hits, including snippets generated by the application of a `Highlighter` to the retrieved documents. The user can then request that the full document be displayed. This document comes from another service that is part of the system I am building.

When the requested document is displayed, I would like to highlight the same terms that were used to retrieve it. I can write some other code to do this without involving the Lucene infrastructure, but since I already have code to generate the snippets, I was hoping to be able to re-use it. (DRY and all that.)

So my question is how best to do this: When the need to mark up a document with search results occurs, the client has the set of terms that were used to retrieve the document and the id of the document that was retrieved. It also knows which fields in the document can be marked up with query terms.

Some possible strategies:

1. Create a query filter that selects only the needed document and then re-run the query only on that document.
2. Somehow (how?) construct a `Scorer` that doesn't depend on a `Query` but that can be seeded with the terms I already have.
3. Skip the Lucene infrastructure entirely.
4. What else?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could index your documents with a [TermVector](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/index.html) which will tell you the position of each term in the original document. Making highlighting trivial. Or simply reuse the [contrib highlighter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/highlighter/index.html)

Comment: yes, that is the idea I have in mind. What I am not sure about about is how to get the highlighter to highlight a document efficiently, after that document has been retrieved, and hte retrieval state (TopDocs, etc.) have been lost.